# Issue with return value from stored procedure in Entity Framework with reverse POCO generator

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, poco

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #CategoryIdsList (CatId INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE #FilteredAdsId (AdsId INT NOT NULL);
.
.
.
SELECT * 
FROM my table

DROP TABLE #CategoryIdsList;
DROP TABLE #FilteredAdsId;
```

but the result set value in poco generator is `int`

```
int myprocedureName(int? count, string ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the **return value** (which is sent back using `RETURN`) is `INT` - as a matter of fact, it's **always** `INT` in SQL Server.

Your data that you selected from `My Table` is the **result set** that the stored procedure produces - which is vastly different from the "return value" .....

Comment: You are right,but my Purpose is result set of poco revese generator of entity framework must be, equal of my select query. not return value of Stored-procedure